# Why would changing a child theme to a normal theme pass a Template is missing. error

Tags: theme-development, child-theme

I have what used to be a child theme but I added to it to the point where its a theme on its own.  I pulled out the Template line in the style.css and now I get the: This theme is broken. Template is missing. error.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error appears when the theme directory has no "index.php" file. For a full theme, an index.php file is required.